# How to control request frequency when using Promise.all()

Tags: node.js

I need some data from another site, So i should request the site one by one, I put the in `promises` array and using `Promise.all(promises)` to do it fast.

But the problem is it is too fast, so the site server block me a while, How to control request frequency when using Promise.all()?

Following is my code:

```
(async() => {
  const request = require('request-promise')

  let promises = []
  let i = 10000
  while( i < 0){
    promises.push(new Promise(async(r) => {
      await request({
        uri: 'http://somehost_i_need_the_data/' + i
      })
      r()
    }))
    i++
  }

  await Promise.all(promises)

})()
```

Comment: @AluanHaddad updated

Comment: The Bluebird promise library has `Promise.map()` that will let you specify how many concurrent requests you want in flight at the same time to keep from over using the target server.  There are also several other stack overflow answers that show how to code that type of logic yourself if you want.  To really solve the problem in the best way, you will need to figure out what the target server is actually limiting (concurrent requests, requests/sec, etc...) and code to that.

Comment: Also, please avoid the promise anti-pattern of surround a promise with a manually created one.  There's no reason for `new Promise()` in your code when `request()` already returns a promise.